# Command prompt to compare different xml-files in different folders to check differences

Tags: loops, command-prompt, file-comparison

I am in a situation where I have a certain bat.file that creates xml-messages. However when me and my colleague use the same data and the same tool to create the messages the amount of the xml-messages aren't the same (they differ with one message).

So what I would like to do now is to perform a some sort of a file comparison check for the messages to see whether the content of the messages are indeed the same (despite having one message less) or whether the information contained in one of the messages is missing from the other messages.

To me this would sound like a job for the fc command and a for loop in command prompt but as I am not an experienced user I can't get my self to write the actual code.

Any suggestions what would be the solution to the problem?

Thanks in advance!